# Updating text in Fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

After changing a fragment (like in the snippet below) I want to update the text that is displayed in one of its views.

```java
Fragment fragment = new LoadingScreen();
String loadScreenTag = "FLSTAG";
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
    .replace(R.id.main_activity_frame, fragment, loadScreenTag)
    .commit();

LoadingScreen lScreen = (LoadingScreen) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(loadScreenTag);                       
lScreen.writeText("some text that does not work");
```

Inside LoadingScreen I have writeText defined

```java
public void writeText(String msg) {
        if (mainView != null) {
            mainView.setText(msg);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "mainView is null at this point");
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am using the card_flip animations to change between fragments (the fragments take up the whole screen, so there is only one visible at any given time).

1. If the previous fragment was another LoadingScreen, the code does not work (no crashes/errors, simply no update to the textView).

   - I assume that it is updating the textView of the LoadingScreen that was just replace. Why is this happening?
2. If the previous fragment was any other fragment, it works, but is uncomfortably slow. Why is it so slow?

Comment: The fragment view was probably not yet created (onCreateView) when you called writeText()... Try waiting few second with a Handler before calling it, that might be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string into the fragment and then render it inside the fragment. So you would have:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("STRING_KEY", "Some string that does not work");
Fragment fragment = new LoadingScreen();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

...
Then inside your LoadingScreen fragment in onCreateView:

```
String myString = getArguments().getString("STRING_KEY");
```

You can easily get access to textview you want to update inside oncreateview via the ViewGroup you are inflating. Then

```
yourTextView.setText(myString);
```